# Replace child Fragment dynamically from Child Fragment itself

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a Viewpager which naturally contain fragments. 
inside one of the fragments I have a sub fragment (child fragment)
each child fragment contains a button which calls the following to replace the child fragment itself

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.containerProfileDetails, new ProfileDetailsAddressFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

just to make it more visual:

1) is the parent fragment

2) is the child fragment.
I need to replace the child fragment by pressing a button inside the child fragment itself

```
┌--------┐
|   1    |
| ┌-----┐|
| | 2   ||
| |     ||
| └-----┘|
└--------┘
```

Note: I know it is possible to replace the fragments using this approach, however, it seems that it is not possible to do this with child fragments as it throws following error.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0104 (com.example.app:id/containerProfileDetails) for fragment ProfileDetailsAddressFragment`

**Update**

Parent Fragment XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.app.fragments.ProfileDetailsFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_page"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    tools:text="2"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerProfileDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Child Fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.fragments.ProfileDetailsUserFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Fragment Profile User Details" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnProfileDetailsUserNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Parent Fragment Java:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_details, container, false);
    lblPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_page);

    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.containerProfileDetails, new ProfileDetailsUserFragment());
    transaction.commit();
    return view;
}
```

Child Fragment Java:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_details_user, container, false);

    Button _btnProfileDetailsUserNext = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnProfileDetailsUserNext);
    _btnProfileDetailsUserNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.containerProfileDetails, new ProfileDetailsAddressFragment());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: normally view pager have no container, which id you are passing as R.id.containerProfileDetails?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar I use `transaction.add(R.id.containerProfileDetails, new firstchildfragment());` to add the first child fragment inside parent fragment

Comment: can you share your xml layout code?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar i assume something is happening and the R.id,containerProfileDetails doesn't return the same ID.

Comment: yeah i m at same but i have to understand your design structure first.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar i have updated the Post with XML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146081/discussion-between-aniruddh-parihar-and-poorya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Replace your Parent Fragment and Child Fragment Code with below

**Parent_Fragment.Java**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_details, container, false);
    lblPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_page);

    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.containerProfileDetails, new ProfileDetailsUserFragment());
    transaction.commit();
    return view;
}
```

**Child_Fragment.Java**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_details_user, container, false);

    Button _btnProfileDetailsUserNext = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnProfileDetailsUserNext);
    _btnProfileDetailsUserNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.containerProfileDetails, new ProfileDetailsAddressFragment());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

I Have not tested the code, it may Produce some compilation error, but way is correct to implement.

Comment: but is it a good idea to create a `public static FragmentManager manager`? wouldn't it be better to create a callback and replace the child fragment from parent fragment ?

Comment: i think  getFragmentManager() will also work in place of getChildFragmentManager() at Child_Fragment.java
try it if it works then i update my answer too.

Comment: @ Aniruddh Parihar you are actually right! I don't understand why but it's working. do you have any references for this ? I would appreciate more details. and i will mark it as answer if you update the post

Comment: I have updated My Answer...you can appreciate my answer as with voteup ans right flag... i will ping you details link of about it.

Comment: here is more details about it.....https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because in the Child Fragment, the fragment transaction is looking for a container with id `R.id.containerProfileDetails`. This container is not in the Child Fragment, but it is in the Parent Fragment.

What you need to do is to create a callback from the Child Fragment to the Parent Fragment. In the Onclick in your Child Fragment, call the callback to the Parent Fragment and then in the Parent Fragment, replace the Child Fragment with the desired Fragment.

Comment: I undestand what you are saying. but i was hopping for a better way. so you are saying there is no way to replace a child fragment from inside itself. because there is no way to get the reference to the parent's childefragmentmanager() inside child fragment itself?

Comment: Nope, unless you are going to keep the parents FragmentManager in a static variable like the answer below, but i would personally prefer the callback method.

Comment: His second suggestion in comments actually work. do you think of any drawbacks ? or possible problems ? He also updated the answer. 
basically using normal fragment manager it is possible to replace the fragment.

Comment: I didn't think of that, it will work. Drawback is is that you're changing the UI of the Parent Fragment in the code of the Child Fragment. Having too much of these constructions could lead to unclear code. You would understand it because you made it, but will someone else who needs to work on your code also understand it?

Comment: Yeh I understand your point of view. but many insist on reducing callbacks. Thanks for the answer